# Multiple serial requests result in empty buffer

Tags: go, tcp, binary, byte

The first TCP connection running on localhost on osx always parses the binary sent to it correctly. Subsequent requests lose the binary data, only seeing the first byte [8]. How have I failed to set up my Reader?

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net"
        "os"
        "app/src/internal/handler"

        "github.com/golang-collections/collections/stack"
)

func main() {
        port := os.Getenv("SERVER_PORT")

        s := stack.New()

        ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("net.Listen: %v", err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Serving on " + port)

        for {
                conn, err := ln.Accept()
                // defer conn.Close()
                if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal("ln.Accept")
                }
                go handler.Handle(conn, s)

        }
}
```

```
package handler

import (
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "log"
        "net"

        "github.com/golang-collections/collections/stack"
)

func Handle(c net.Conn, s *stack.Stack) {
        fmt.Printf("Serving %s\n", c.RemoteAddr().String())

        buf := make([]byte, 0, 256)
        tmp := make([]byte, 128)

        n, err := c.Read(tmp)
        if err != nil {
                if err != io.EOF {
                        log.Fatalf("connection Read() %v", err)
                }
                return
        }

        buf = append(buf, tmp[:n]...)
}
```

log:

```
Serving [::1]:51699
 ------------- value ---------------:QCXhoy5t
Buffer Length: 9. First Value: 8
Serving [::1]:51700
------------- value ---------------:
Buffer Length: 1. First Value: 8
Serving [::1]:51701
```

test sent over:

```
push random string:
QCXhoy5t

push random string:
GPh0EnbS
push random string:
4kJ0wN0R
```

Comment: How are messaged framed in the protocol (length, delimiter, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for [Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) say:

```
Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n 
<= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read returns n < len(p), it may use 
all of p as scratch space during the call. If some data is available but not 
len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting 
for more.
```

So the most likely cause of your issue is that Read is returning the data available (in this case a single character). You can fix this by using [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) or performing the read in a loop (the fact the data is being added to a buffer makes it look like that was the original intention) with something like:

```
for {
    n, err := c.Read(tmp)
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            // Note that data might have also been received - you should process that
            // if appropriate.
            log.Fatalf("connection Read() %v", err)
            return
        }
        break // All data received so process it
    }
    buf = append(buf, tmp[:n]...)
}
```

*Note:* There is no guarantee that any data is received; you should check the length before trying to access it (i.e. `buf[0]` may panic)